# AngularJS: retrieve array from object after $http get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Sorry I am new to Angular. And this is probably dump question. 
I have following data structure in a json:

```
[
    {"id": "1", "name": "Alan", "location": "US"}, 
    {"id": "2", "name": "Bella", "location": "UK"}
]
```

I have following service:

```
    let users = getData();

    function getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    function getData() {
        return $http
            .get("./data/users.json")
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
    }
    function addUser(user) {
        let id = users.$$state.value[users.$$state.value.length - 1].id++;
        users.$$state.value.push({
              // adding user
        })
    }
```

I am obtaining some very inconvenient object from `$http.get`. How to get it back to array representation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: have you tried: **return jQuery.parseJSON(response.data);** ?

Comment: I am not using jQuery, I use angular

Comment: try : **JSON.parse(response.data)**

Comment: $http.get("./data/users.json").then(onUserComplete);
 var onUserComplete = function(response){$scope.user = response.data;}

Unless I'm missing the main point of what you're trying the above two lines should be able to replace everything you written so far

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ I know you are using angular and i proposed you the usage of that jQuery function. If you cannot use jQuery you could use *return angular.fromJson(response.data);*

Comment: @Cecilia actually `$http` default response transform already do that. The problem here is about how promises works.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro you are right ! I'd check your answer as useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the lack of compreension on how [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) work, your [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) call is not returning the response, but a promise of that request which is async. Promises are used exactly for this scenario, when you have async tasks and need to subscribe callbacks to its resolution.

Anyways, instead of trying to use the promise returned directly, you must subscribe a callback to the success topic, which in promises is given by the `then(fn)` method and feed your variable with the data returned from your chained promise on the `$http.get().then ...$`.

For example:

```
let users = [];

getData()
    .then(function (data) {
        users = data;
    });

function getUsers() {
    return users;
}

function getData() {
    return $http
        .get("./data/users.json")
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
}

function addUser(user) {
    let id = users.$$state.value[users.$$state.value.length - 1].id++;
    users.$$state.value.push({
          // adding user
    })
}
```